# Storing JSON Solr query data in a Javascript array - (undefined)

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, solr, storing-data

Im in javascript on a HTML page trying to use Solr query data in a table.

So what I want to do is get a bunch of different responses to solr queries, and store them in an array as they come in. Then return each of these results to their relevant spot in a graphic chart to display my information.

What I am having trouble doing is storing the result from JSON in a variable for later use. However it won't save, as the results show up as undefined when checked. Yet if I assign the response to some HTML location like with `$('#yoyo')` from within `function on_data(data)`, it seems to work just fine.

So I can get results live, but I can't store them for some reason?
From reading lots of other posts it seems it could be something to do with it being asynchronous. It feels to me like functions are running out of time. Like its trying to return the answer before it's assigned any value or something.

Can somebody show me where I'm going wrong here?

```
           if (typeof variable !== 'undefined') {
                var global_tick = -1
            }

            var results = []

            var testB = 'query response failed';
            $('#testB').prepend('<div>' + testB + '</div>');

            function on_data(data) {

                results[global_tick] = parseInt(data.response.numFound);

                $('#yoyo').prepend('<div>' + results[global_tick] + '</div>');

                global_tick = global_tick + 1;
            }

            function partyQuery(party, region){
                pQuery(party, region)
                var res = pResult()
                return res
            }

            function pQuery(party, region){

                var url='http://localhost:8983/solr/articles/select?q=text:'+party+'+AND+region:'+region+'&wt=json&callback=?&json.wrf=on_data';
                $.getJSON(url);
            }

            function pResult(){
                return results[global_tick]
            }

            //Parties
            var pqFG = partyQuery("\"Fine Gael\"", 'ROI');
            var pqFF = partyQuery("\"Fianna Fail\"", 'ROI');

            // Load the Visualization API and the corechart package.
            google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});

            // Set a callback to run when the Google Visualization API is loaded.
            google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

            // Callback that creates and populates a data table,
            // instantiates the pie chart, passes in the data and
            // draws it.
            function drawChart() {
            // Party data table.
            var data_party = new google.visualization.DataTable();
            data_party.addColumn('string', 'Party');
            data_party.addColumn('number', 'Mentions');
            data_party.addRows([
              ['Fine Gael', pqFG],
              ['Fianna Fáil', pqFF],
            ]);
```

Comment: `$.getJSON(url);` ... you basically ignore the response here - oh, I see, you're using JSONP not AJAX

Comment: the 'on_data(data)' function is called, code in there can affect output as with '#yoyo'. I can show all the results I want in HTML. But it won't store any variables for me.